# Performing sphere casting in Libgdx 3D

Tags: 3d, libgdx, bulletphysics

I am developing a billiards game in libgdx 3D and bullet physics. I want to show  collision hint like 8 ball pool.I have tried with ray casing but it was not accurate with shpere.so i need help to perform sphere casting like unity.

Comment: I think you mean path or trajectory prediction (what would happen if i would hit this ball this hard at this location, including bouncing of walls and other balls and such). For that I'd think that simply stepping the world and see where it goes would be the easiest solution. You could use a separate world (a parallel world) for that where everything except the one ball is static.

Comment: hi @Xoppa thanks for suggestion. I am using btDynamicsWorld so could you please tell me how can i proceed.